# What's the point of pads without any IC attached to them found in some boards?

Tags: motherboard, pin

I've come across many motherboards (or even generic electronics boards) that have what seem to be pads that should be attached to some IC, but are left disconnected.

[image: Xbox motherboard with arrows pointing to the pins]

What's the purpose of them?

Comment: "What's the purpose of them?"  Could be lots of reasons.  Chips for options that model doesn't have, legacy spots no longer needed in latest revision, test device attachment points, etc.

Comment: Those are not *"pins"*.  They are called pads.

Comment: Isn't this question Offtopic for SuperUser?

Comment: @LPChip no, it's even written in the FAQ.

Answer (score 2):

In the particular photo you showed, those are lands for additional RAM. In each case you can see a RAM chip (below the top empty space and to the left of the bottom one) placed next to the empty spot.

This probably permits the RAM on this board to be doubled without having to make changes to the circuit board. It's also possible that these lands instead exist to support lower-density RAM (should that be cheaper during a particular manufacturing run) and this particular board was filled with two higher-density RAM chips leaving these spots blank.

Comment: Yep. That is very common. If you need to produce several millions of PCB's saving 1 dollar on each PCB is well worth the effort to incorporate this kind of flexibility in a PCB design. The RAM chips are often one of the most expensive components and the prices can vary a lot over time. E.g.: We can fit the board with 4x 2GB RAM or 2x 4GB RAM. Which variant we do this month depends on which RAM size is cheapest to purchase at this time.

Answer (score 1):

These types of pads are there to allow for a chip to be put there on variations of the product that do in fact use the extra space. By being able to use essentially the same board for these variations, the need to design, validate, and manufacture two different boards is avoided, which can significantly reduce manufacturing cost.

This is pretty common with SSDs, too; being able to use the same board for different capacity versions of the drive makes it cheaper to manufacture due to economies of scale. The example below is a recent-model SSD, the Toshiba OCZ VX500; the 256 GB, 512 GB, and 1 TB models are shown. Notice that not every NAND pad on the 256 GB model is actually populated with NAND and that only the 1 TB model has the DRAM pad populated (image credit [AnandTech](http://www.anandtech.com/show/10674/the-toshiba-ocz-vx500-ssd-review)):

[image: Variations of the OCZ VX500 SSD with different numbers of pads populated]